# SQL - BCP out problems with login credentials

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, bcp

So I've been surfing through some of the questions related to my issue but I still can't seem to solve it. I had this working on my own SQL server but as soon as I moved it to a different server I now have an issue.

Here is the bcp out command I am using:

```
declare @sql varchar(1000)
set @sql = 'bcp DatabaseName.dbo.TableName out C:\'+@name+'.txt -c -t"\t" -T -U"'+@user+'" -P"'+@password+'" -S"'+ @@SERVERNAME +'"'

exec master..xp_cmdshell @sql
```

But I am getting this in return from the server:

```
SQLState = 37000, NativeError = 4060
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Cannot open database "DatabaseName" requested by the login. The login failed.
SQLState = 28000, NativeError = 18456
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'.
NULL
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong right now and I've tried doing the fixes I've seen in other threads about it but still nothing.

**Edit:** I previously used this command on my own server and it worked just fine.

```
declare @sql varchar(1000)
set @sql = 'bcp DatabaseName.dbo.TableName out C:\'+@name+'.txt -c -t"\t" -T -S'+ @@SERVERNAME
```

I also removed the -T in my first command and it had a login failed for the user instead of the NT Authority system account. Even though the login is correct.

Solved... I'm stupid.

Answer (score 1):

Options for **bcp** command line:

> -S server name
>   -T trusted connection
>   -w wide character type
>   -t field terminator

```
bcp AdventureWorks2014.HumanResources.vEmployee out C:\DataFiles\SsisExample\source\EmployeeData.txt -w -t, -S localhost\SqlSrv2014 -T
```